# Python contact book project for beginner

Tags: python, project

How can I take multiple inputs from user (without the use of a GUI) such as name, phone number, email or ID and store them in a variable in python. I want to show them to the user later when they search for it. I am a beginner.

```
print('Contact Book')
print('''Press I to update contact
Press S to scearch''')


def updateContact():
    Name = input('Enter Your Name: ')
    MobileNo = input("Enter mobile: ")
    NameList = [].append(Name)


userinput = input("Press Key: ")
if userinput.upper().strip() == 'S':
    updateContact()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a `Contact` [class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html), which will contain attributes such as `name` and `mobileNo`. In the `__init__` method (the constructor of the class), you can initialize those attributes, then print them in a separate method `showInfo`.

```
class Contact():
    def __init__(self):  # Constructor
        self.name = input("Enter Your Name: ")
        self.mobileNo = input("Enter mobile: ")

    def showInfo(self):  # Prints info
        print("name :", self.name, ", mobile no :", self.mobileNo)


first_contact = Contact()  # New instance of the class Contact, calls __init__()
first_contact.showInfo()  # Calls showInfo() on first_contact, which prints its attributes
```

Comment: Thanka a lot sir...Seems like i need t learn pythonobject oriented programing before diving into deep and do projects like this.....Thanks again

Comment: @SultanulArefin No worries, feel free to accept the answer if you don't have any other question.

Comment: accepted it...may lord bless you...just a question,is OOP nessesary for doing projects like this?..or i can do this kind pf programming in a conventional way

Comment: @SultanulArefin I'd say it's necessary in this case, because `name` and `mobileNo` are attributes that define a `Contact`. Appending them to lists or dictionaries would be very confusing and not easy to use compared to using OOP. Especially since you are trying to make a list of contacts, it's way more readable to make a list of `Contact` objects than trying to match numbers and names in an unordered list. Remember that readability is the most important feature in any code.